# Using relative paths in SASS background images

Tags: css, webpack, sass, relative-path

I'm trying to get background images to work in my Angular project's SASS when I don't know where the application root will be.  For example, the app's home page could be:

```
localhost:9000/home
```

or

```
localhost:9000/foo/home
```

or

```
localhost:9000/bar/home
```

I figured I could address this by just making the paths in my background-image properties relative, like this:

```
div {
    background-image: url("assets/smiley.png");
}
```

However, that doesn't work. When I compile the app, it can't find the assets.  In the console, it says:

```
Error: Can't resolve './assets/smiley.png'
```

It gives me this same message whether my background-image url value starts with ./ or not.  But even ./ I imagine should work.

What DOES work is if I hard-code the path into the background-image property, making the path ABSOLUTE, like so:

```
div {
    background-image: url("/foo/assets/smiley.png");
}
```

However, that's not an option, since I don't know if the app root will be at /foo/ or /bar/ or something else.

Another thing that works is using the --base-href option of ng build to hard-code the path, like so:

```
ng build --base-href /foo/
```

But if possible, I'd really like to accomplish this with code changes that don't involve passing parameters to the ng build command on a build-by-build basis.

Here is my Webpack Config located at node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config.js.  Is that the right file?  Sorry if it's not - I'm pretty unfamiliar with webpack:

```
/**
 * Adapted from angular2-webpack-starter
 */

const helpers = require('./config/helpers'),
    webpack = require('webpack');

/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    entry: helpers.root('ng2-translate.ts'),

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('bundles'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'ng2-translate.umd.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        library: 'ng2-translate'
    },

    // require those dependencies but don't bundle them
    externals: [/^\@angular\//, /^rxjs\//],

    module: {
        rules: [{
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'tslint-loader',
            exclude: [helpers.root('node_modules')]
        }, {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader?declaration=false',
            exclude: [/\.e2e\.ts$/]
        }]
    },

    plugins: [
        // fix the warning in ./~/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            helpers.root('./src')
        ),

        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                tslintLoader: {
                    emitErrors: false,
                    failOnHint: false
                }
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Where are assets located relative to your app root?

Comment: That's the thing - we don't know.  Once the application is built, the client can put it anywhere relative to the root.  That's why we need everything to be relative.  We have everything working with the exception of the bakground-image URL's, which appear to need to be absolute.

Comment: it simply sounds as if in your case assets may be in ../assets/ instead of ./assets/

Comment: can you share your webpack config? what version webpack?

Comment: @miir I think it's webpack 2.2.1 based on "npm list webpack", and I've added the webpack config above, though I'm not sure if I gave you the right file.  Let me know if I gave you the wrong config file.

Comment: @Gnudiff my assets folder is located at ROOT/src/assets

Comment: @Gnudiff I think you may be onto something.  I think it really may be that simple.  Investigating now.

Comment: @Gnudiff  Yup, that was it. Wow, I didn't expect it to be that simple.  My path needed to look like "../../../assets..."  Problem solved!

Comment: @David glad it helped. You might upvote the relevant comment if you found it useful - don't think there is point in writing an answer.